# Dynamic creation of linked image with JSF 2.2 (Primefaces 5.0)

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

JSF 2.2, Primefaces 5.0,

What I want is just an image which links to a website. This should be generated using Java.

JSF:

```
<ui:component binding="#{bean.content}" />
```

Bean:

```
public UIComponent getContent() {
    GraphicImage image = (GraphicImage) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getApplication().createComponent(GraphicImage.COMPONENT_TYPE);
    image.setValue(imagePath);

    Link link = (Link) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getApplication().createComponent(Link.COMPONENT_TYPE);
    link.setHref(uri);

    ...
}
```

How can I put an image into the link tag?

I tried `link.setValue(image)`. It didn't work. Just got the toString representation of the image object.

The result HTML should be something like:

`<a href="www.uri.com"><img src="image.jpg"></a>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this works..

```
public UIComponent getContent() {
GraphicImage image = (GraphicImage) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getApplication().createComponent(GraphicImage.COMPONENT_TYPE);
image.setUrl("yourimage.jpg");
image.setOnclick("window.open('http://stackoverflow.com');");
return image;
}
```

Change the path and url accordingly.

Comment: OP just wants to add image as child of link.

Comment: @BalusC thanks sir for pointing out that the code does not produce an image wrapped by a link. But since the answer has been accepted I will leave it like this.